# c# Word Application PrintPreview

Tags: c#, cpu-word

[image: ![abc.PNG]

How can i close printpreview without edit document?

Comment: Editing id the default Word Mode, what would you like to happen? Close Word?

Comment: @XavierAM Yes, I want to close immediate

Comment: VBA can do that, but I don't know what is the difference with c#

Comment: How do you do it with VBA?

Comment: If pIsPreview = True Then
        Call VPUWordAppli.Run("PreviewAndQuit")
    Else
        Call VPUWordAppli.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(False)
        Call VPUWordAppli.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    End If

Comment: Set VPUWordAppli = New Word.Application

Comment: There is no way to do it in native word mode. It actually doesn't make sense. But you can still create a macro or a vsto add in to emulate this behavior.